# While loop not producing correct results

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to use a while-loop to ask the user for a number between 1 and 10.  While the user fails to enter a number between 1 and 10 (inclusive), I want to ask them for another number.

My code so far is:

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number.");
while (i <= 10)
{
    Console.ReadLine();

    if (i > 1 && i < 10)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        continue;
    }

    if (i < 1 && i > 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter New Number...");
        break;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please use a more detailed headline for your question (that it's a c# question can be recognizes by tags...)

Comment: it would be nice if you accepted an answer that helped you. at least 4 did :) SLaks's is the best since it gave you all the answers and made you think a bit ^^

Comment: also a side note : never use "i" as a global variable. it will confuse the hell out of you later on :D

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check mark.

Answer (score 15):

You're writing `if (i < 1 && i > 10)`.
`i` can never be both less than 1 and more than `10`.
(Hint: 'and' is the wrong word)

Also, you never assigned a value to `i`.
(Hint: call [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx))

Also, you probably want to swap `break` (which stops looping) and `continue` (which continues looping)

Also, what should the condition in the `while` loop be?

Comment: best answer ;) it teaches not gives the ready code on a plate ^^

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 1 || i > 10)
{
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out i);
}
```

or with text

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out i);
while (i < 1 || i > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out i);
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i < 1 && i > 10)
```

to

```
if (i < 1 || i > 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You never assign anything but 0 to `i` - so that it will never actually change. You need to parse the user input.
- `(i < 1) && (i > 10)` can never be true, you may want to use the logical or operator `||` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is `if (i > 1 && i < 10)` really what you want? It checks to see if a number is greater than 1 and less than 10. What if the number is 1 or 10?

Comment: he wants the number to be between 1 and 10.

Comment: The wording "enter a number between 1 and 10 (inclusive)" leads me to believe that 1 and 10 should be considered part of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the conditional being incorrect, it should be:

```
if(i < 1 || i > 10)
```

You're also not assigning i to be anything. You use Console.ReadLine() but you're not actually dumping it into i. This drops you into an infinite loop.

You also run the risk of type issues if the value you're receiving isn't an integer. You should perform some type conversions and numeric checks to prevent casting problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested code**

```
int i = 0;
int count = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number.");
while (count <= 10)
{
   i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

   if (i > 1 && i < 10)
   {
       count++;
       continue;

   }
   if (i < 1 || i > 10)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter New Number...");
      continue;
   }
}
```